# Attempted import error: 'startTransition' is not exported from 'react' (imported as 'React')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am receiving the following error when trying to build my React app:

Attempted import error: 'startTransition' is not exported from 'react' (imported as 'React')

It doesn't show anything else like the file or line that needs to be fixed. The weird thing is that I can build the same project in a different server.

The settings on the two servers are slightly different.

**Server that is working has:**

```
Ubuntu 20.02
Node v16.13.2
npm 8.3.2
react 18.2.0
```

**Sever that doesn't create the build:**

```
Amazon Linux release 2 (Karoo) - centos rhel fedora
Node v16.20.0
npm 8.19.4
react 18.2.0
```

My package.json has the following dependencies:
[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeBIv.png)

I'm trying to build using: npm run build

Where can I start looking?

thanks

Comment: You should make sure you actually have the dependency versions which you think you do. You have multiple packages which depend on react and the version you specify is ^17

Comment: Thanks Aluan, How do I do that? npm update?

Comment: You can also just run npm install react

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with the version of react-router-dom.

[https://github.com/backstage/backstage/issues/18155#:~:text=Looks%20like%206.12.1%20has](https://github.com/backstage/backstage/issues/18155#:%7E:text=Looks%20like%206.12.1%20has)